# React-Native-Gesture-Handler failed during code execution on Android

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use the react-native-navigation library for my project but in order to use it I need the gesture handler. I install it and edit the MainActivity.jar as it says on the website for react-navigation and react-native-gesture-handler. But whenever I try and run my code using "react-native start" and "react-native run-android" it tries and compiles everything but then fails and gives me this error message:

```
 > Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
20 actionable tasks: 20 executed
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm i jetifier`
`npx jetify`

fixed it for me on rn 0.6

https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/647#issuecomment-508459010

Comment: After i try to use `react-native run-android` it shows that it completed the build successfully but doesn't run the app, and if i try to launch it manually it doesn't launch either..?

Comment: does `react-native run-android` open a metro for you?

Comment: No but I open one on my own. Also I reinstalled npm modules and that fixed it somehow

Comment: if it's got fixed great! but if your metro didn't run automatically you should first run `npm start` then in a new terminal run `react-native run-android` and everything works well.

Answer (score 2):

In my MacOS, it can't not find exactly Java SDK Home
Please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64968851/could-not-find-tools-jar-please-check-that-library-internet-plug-ins-javaapple) to fix your issue